# Xamarin undeclared xmlns prefix/Type StaticResource not found in xmlns

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I really need help with the next xaml errors. They only show when building the solution, not before

Given then next partial code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:skiarate="clr-namespace:SkiaRate;assembly=SkiaRate.Forms"
         xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
         x:Class="Project.Views.ProductDetailPage"
         xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:Project.Helpers"
         BindingContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

And asociated xaml.cs file

```
namespace Project.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ProductDetailPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ProductDetailPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
    }
}
```

I get

> Position 55:93. Undeclared xmlns prefix 'i18n'

Where line 55 is

```
<Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,10,0,0" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" Text="{i18n:Translate Telephone}"/>
```

I have used the exact same lines in other xaml pages, and it doesn't throw this error.

**Things that I have tried**:

-Delete line 55, error changes to

> Position 10:14. Type StaticResource not found in xmlns

(I use binding with the main page on all my xaml pages, and only crashes in this one)

-Clean, build, rebuild, in all posible orders with the next 2 items

-Delete obj and bin contents

-Delete packages content (both from local project and local pc's user)

-Copy a page that does not have errors, modify it's header to the new page name, then error shows. (I tried this several times with several names)

-Create a content page from zero, create header manually, copy the ContentPage.Content from the previous page

-Change xaml's page properties (custom tool)

-Update Xamarin.Forms to last version pre-3.2.*. After doing this I changed to 3.1 again

What else can I try?

Note: All this started when I installed Rg.Plugins.Popup to convert this page to a popup page, then I deleted the changes on this page, and tried with deleting the libraries too.

Comment: Is this a valid Binding `BindingContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`. I can't say I have ever used/come across it before

Comment: Yes it is valid, I have used it in all xaml pages

Comment: You learn something new everyday:). Two possible points to check; 1) have you tried turning it off and on again? Sometimes VS gets in to a bad state and although it reports some errors they aren’t truly there. 2) when removing the RgPlugins library you didn’t by any chance remove anything else? A good diff tool from your chosen source control should help there

Comment: Yes I tried to turn off and on again. I don't think so, maybe when I installed RgPlugins some library got updated, I don't remember clearly. I will rollback all changes to last commit and hope that this error doesn't show up anymore. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Julian87 do you use any framework such as Prism or other ?

Comment: Hello toumir, no I don't. I already found the error. It was a grid that had an empty column definition tag (I used it before to make 2 columns and then I erased them, but not the grid.columndefinitions). Is this a bug? Or it is just not recognized on design time?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the code in `Project.Helpers.Translate`. Could you post that code, please?